# Company buy-out has moved my Salary Review back

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [Company buy-out has moved my Salary Review back](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59398/company-buy-out-has-moved-my-salary-review-back) was closed yesterday (I believe for being unclear), and after a couple edits, it was reopened. Now the question has gotten two new close votes for being unclear again.

I don't know what's so unclear about it. The OP had a salary review scheduled, which should have happened before the company was bought out. Now that the buy-out is happening, the OP is worried they won't get their salary review for another year. The question is pretty clearly stated after Myles's edit:

> How can I make sure that I get an opportunity to address this without
>   being locked into my starting wage for an unreasonable period?

What can we do to help this question? I really don't know why people are still voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

I made an edit to the title/question body.

At first glance, it's pretty long and the core question was buried in a middle paragraph (the title wasn't super helpful, either).

Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 2):

There's a question mark in there, but the post doesn't make sense without further information.

Two users posted comments requesting additional information but while the OP is active, he hasn't replied or edited the post since the original off-topic close. Since scanning didn't show a question, the OP didn't respond and the title also didn't have a question I voted to close as unclear. There's nothing to answer until we work out what the OP's goals and restrictions are, for instance: why he can't just ask for a raise.